# Is it possible to get information on the control on which an event was issued in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create one event handler for button clicks and connect that to multiple buttons (creating a simple calculator where pressing each number adds its text to the lineEdit).

In C# we would use the sender object which was passed as a parameter and then cast it back to Button and get its Text or other needed property and go on.

I am new to Qt, Do we have such a thing or a similar approach in Qt?  Since I couldn't get it out of the signal/slot method of Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `QObject / QWidget` that receives the signal, call `this->sender()` ([QObject::sender](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#sender)()), and cast it with `dynamic_cast<MyWidgetType*>(...)`

Comment: @Lol4t0: I'm not familiar with QSignalMapper, though I see it now in the documentation. Could you write an answer so I can benefit as well? QObject::sender() does do what the OP is describing, but now I'm curious about your suggested solution!

Comment: `QSignalMapper` indeed can be used here but `sender()` is more common, convenient and efficient. I don't see a reason why `QSignalMapper` should be used here.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some good examples here for linking back to the issuer of an event.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html

They give you different examples for

- The sender() Approach (like Jamin Grey's approach below)
- The Subclass Approach
- The Signal Mapper Approach